Translate complete webpages using Google Cloud Translation API
Require to translate the whole webpage using Google Cloud Translation API and not just some text. ( DOc: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/overview ). How do I proceed with building this? The API takes html as a request but does not take the whole page, it runs into Error 413 Text too large.
Implemented the Cloud Translation API and sent in the html doc in the q parameter.

Please post code snippet of your implementation. also, check the API quota here https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas
